# "onmouseout" isn't working. The image doesn't change

Tags: javascript

I want an image to change when it is hovered on. So far my code is fine. But I want the image to change back to its original image when mouse leaves the image. This is where my code doesn't work properly. What is the problem and how can I fix it? I really appreciate your help.

This is my html code:

```
<div onmouseover="show_large(this);" onmouseout="show_normal(this);">
  <img src="2.JPG">
</div>
<script>
function show_large(element){
  element.innerHTML=
  '<img src="1.JPG">';
}
function show_normal(element){
  element.innerHTML=
  '<img src="2.JPG">';
}
</script>
```

And this is my css code:

```
div{
  width: 25%;
  margin: 0;
}
img{
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you create a [small demo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for this using [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or [snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358993/1823841) here to show the issue happening.

Comment: @palaѕн Isn't the description clear enough? The image doesn't change back to what it was when mouse leaves the area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since images will have default hover events, you need to disable them for it to work on the parent div. You can disable them by adding `pointer-events: none` to `img` tag

```js
function show_large(element) {
  element.innerHTML =
    '<img src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/51.jpg">';
}

function show_normal(element) {
  element.innerHTML =
    '<img src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/50.jpg">';
}
```

```css
div {
  width: 25%;
  margin: 0;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<div onmouseover="show_large(this);" onmouseout="show_normal(this);">
  <img src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/50.jpg">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can achive this only with CSS and HTML, just add `background-image` property on your div and change img on `:hover`, like so:

```css
div{
background-image: url('first-img-src.png');
transition: background-image 1s ease-in-out;
}
div:hover{
background-image: url('second-img-src.png');
}
```

EDIT:
You can achive same thing using `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` with changeing `img.src` property:

```js
const img = document.querySelector('img');
img.addEventListener('mouseenter', (e) => {
  img.src = 'second.png'
})
img.addEventListener('mouseleave', (e) => {
  img.src = 'first.png'
})
```

Comment: Not a good Idea to make it as `background-image`. Will loose the scope of <img /> tag

Comment: Could you please just correct my code and not suggest another solution? For some reasons I don't want to change my code so drastically. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do it using css it self. working [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t356venh/)

```css
.image-container{
  width: 300px;
}
.over{
  display: none;
}
.image-container:hover .main{
  display: none;
}
.image-container:hover .over{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-container">
    <img class="main" src="https://www.rd.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/shutterstock_1013848126.jpg" width="100%" />
    <img class="over" src="https://www.rd.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/shutterstock_671541538-e1557714950453.jpg"  width="100%" />
</div>
```